# What does "I ween that you are better where you are" in "The Heart of the Raven" mean?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics, wording-choice, mono-inc

The chorus of the song "[The Heart of the Raven](https://genius.com/Mono-inc-the-heart-of-the-raven-lyrics)" by the German band MONO INC. goes like this:

> But here in the raven's heart
> Your heart is beating on
> I ween that you are better where you are
> You're here in the raven's heart
> No matter where you've gone
> I'm sure that you are there among the stars

The line "I ween that you are better where you are" struck me as odd. First off, I wasn't familiar with the word "ween" so I looked it up. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ween) defines it as an archaic word meaning "think":

> Definition of ween
> transitive verb
> archaic
> : to hold as an opinion : SUPPOSE, BELIEVE

But... what does that mean here in context? Why use such an archaic and unknown word here, instead of a word found in more people's lexicons? How does this affect the song?

Comment: Ween [is cognate to](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ween#Etymology_2) the German verb [wähnen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/w%C3%A4hnen#German), meaning *to suppose, expect, believe, imagine.* It may not seem quite so obscure and unknown to native German speakers.

Comment: The only time I ever heard the word is in Gilbert & Sullivan: "That junior partnership I ween ... "  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZ-gfalEWI0